# Issue with Drupal 8 CiviCRM Views + CiviCRM event

Tags: civievent, drupal-views, civicrm-entity, drupal-8

Does anyone know how to create a Drupal view to show only future/upcoming CiviCRM events in Drupal 8?
I tried by adding the Event start date as filter but it doesn't provide the filtering options to set the date or choose an offset like it did in D7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked and this is working using the latest D8 CiviCRM Entity - it is under development, so best to use the latest directly from its GitHub Repo:

```
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/tree/8.x-3.x
```

If you're interested in helping us to advance/accelerate this development - consider becoming a Maker/sponsor of the D8 integration projects (D8 Webform CiviCRM and D8 CiviCRM Entity) modules.

[image]